# Show a div when another div is visible inside first div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with a class of `.productSelectInput` that dynamiclly shows for of only a few of my products, so I hide divs with a class of `.options` initially with CSS, but when `.productSelectInput` is visible I want `.options` to show again. I thought my JS below would work but it does not seem to. I thought it may be because `.productSelectInput` is inside the options class. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="options">
   <div class="option">
      <label for="o1">Choose:</label>
      <select id="Grouping_6350746" class="productSelectInput"
      name="AddToCart_Grouping" onchange="DrawProduct(311820,6350746,this.value,'',4);">
         <option value="6350744">Kiwi</option>
         <option value="6350745">Marigold</option>
         <option value="6350746" selected="selected">Strawberry</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:
       .options { display: none; }

Here is my js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    if ($( ".productSelectInput" ).is(":visible") ) {
        $( ".options" ).show();
    }
 });
```

SOLVED:  Hide options with js worked.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    if ($( ".productSelectInput" ).is(":visible") ) {
    $( ".options" ).show();
    } else {
    $( ".options" ).hide();
    }
 });
```

Comment: .productSelectInput is a select dropdown or div?

Comment: How will your select ever show if it's will always be hidden since options is hidden and it wraps your select?

Comment: Here's what I mean.. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve..  `.productSelectInput` will never be visible until `.options` is visible http://jsfiddle.net/uKjFA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hiding `.options` via JavaScript instead of CSS. JavaScript may not be able to `show()`
elements it didn't `hide()` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is executed only once : when the document is ready. It's not called each time something changes in your page.

And since `.productSelectInput` is initially hidden, it's normal the `.options` isn't visible.

If you want your `.options` to become visible, you have to make the test each time it is possible that `.productSelectInput` becomes visible. The simplest is to put it just where you make `.productSelectInput` visible.

And to prevent your question : there is no event raised when an element becomes visible. You *could* check that periodically but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to get the closest parent and show only that 1:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
  if ($( ".productSelectInput" ).is(":visible") ) {
    $(this).closest( ".options" ).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: maybe not..it's hard to tell if you have more than one of these div.options on the page

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown should be outside of the div
otherwise, it wont be visible to change, as the parent element is being hidden